# Navigate to another page and back without re-rendering/refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, refresh

I have a product page with many articles. There is also a filter for the products. The products are displayed one-by-one using an infinity scroll/intersection observer. If I navigate to my profile page and back, the entire page is rerendered and everything is gone. How can I prevent this?

```
import Link from "next/link";

<Link
  href={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}`}
  shallow={true}
  className="inline-flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-5 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 group"
>
  <HomeIcon className="h-8 dark:text-white"></HomeIcon>

  <span className="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-blue-600 dark:group-hover:text-blue-500">
    Home
  </span>
</Link>
```

MainPage.js

```
export default function MainImage() {
  ...
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {       
    fetchProducts();   
  }, [page]);

  ...
}
```